# Check spelling of words containing a period (dot) character on the command line

Tags: command-line, continuous-integration, spell-checking, hunspell, aspell

I'm trying to get our CI/CD pipeline to spell check a website. To make it work we need a custom dictionary of correct words e.g. names of products. I tried Aspell and Hunspell, but in both cases I've ran into the same problem - names with period in them, e.g. "Node.js". It's considered to be two words: "Node" and "js", where second is incorrect.

I'd like to make a list of words like that so they are considered correct. Some considerations:

- I don't want to add word "js" as it is not a correct word (capitalized "JS" is a valid abbreviation). Also it's just an example. There can be more compounds like this.
- The setup should be encapsulated in the project, i.e. require no custom modifications to the host environment.

Here's what I have so far (not working):

The `sample.txt` file with some spelling errors:

```
The cat was on the rooof with Fana. They were using Node.js to do their shtuff.
```

Custom dictionary for Aspell (`custom.pws`):

```
personal_ws-1.1 en 2
Fana
Node.js
```

```
$ aspell list --home-dir=. --personal=custom.pws sample.txt
Error: ./custom.pws: The word "Node.js" is invalid. The character '.' (U+2E) may not appear in the middle of a word.
```

Custom dictionary for Hunspell (`custom.dic`):

```
Fana
Node.js
```

```
$ hunspell -p custom.dic -l sample.txt
rooof
js
shtuff
```